# MySQL: Get the final score for each player for a given date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores scores of each player based on date. A player can have multiple scores saved for same date as he proceeds through the game. Example data is for date `2015-10-01` is:

```
id     player_id     score        score_date
------------------------------------------------------
1      100           3200         2015-10-10 10:10:37
2      101           1750         2015-10-10 10:12:42
3      100           1100         2015-10-10 10:19:50
4      102           4100         2015-10-11 10:24:22
5      101           3000         2015-10-09 10:32:44
```

As you can see here, `player 100` has two scores in this table. His final score for the date is 1100. `player 101` has two scores too, but for the selected date he only has one score. `player 102` does not have any score for the selected date.

How can I write a query that will fetch me the final score record of the each player for that particular date? The result I want is:

```
player_id     score        date
------------------------------------------------------
100           1100         2015-10-10 10:19:50
101           3000         2015-10-09 10:32:44
```

I tried to frame this question earlier, but ended up messing up the actual point and it turned into a different question (for which I got an excellent answer btw).I hope someone will help me solve this problem because I am really stuck here :(

Comment: why give me a -1 without an explanation?

Comment: Perhaps because it's the single most frequently asked question under this tag. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too.

Answer (score 2):

### schema

```
create table scores
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    player_id int not null,
    score int not null,
    score_date datetime not null
);
insert scores(player_id,score,score_date) values
(100, 3200, '2015-10-10 10:10:37'),
(101, 1750, '2015-10-10 10:12:42'),
(100, 1100, '2015-10-10 10:19:50'),
(102, 4100, '2015-10-11 10:24:22'),
(101, 3000, '2015-10-09 10:32:44'),
(105, 6666, '2015-10-09 10:00:44');
```

### Last score thru 2015-10-10 achieved on any date

```
SELECT  a.player_id,a.score
FROM    scores a
JOIN
(   SELECT  player_id, MAX(score_date) as weCareAbout
    FROM    scores
    where score_date<date('2015-10-11')
    GROUP BY player_id
) b 
ON b.player_id=a.player_id and b.weCareAbout=a.score_date
order by a.player_id;
+-----------+-------+
| player_id | score |
+-----------+-------+
|       100 |  1100 |
|       101 |  1750 |
|       105 |  6666 |
+-----------+-------+
```

### Last score on 2015-10-10 and scores only on that date

```
SELECT  a.player_id,a.score
FROM    scores a
JOIN
(   SELECT  player_id, MAX(score_date) as weCareAbout
    FROM    scores
    where date(score_date)='2015-10-10'
    GROUP BY player_id
) b 
ON b.player_id=a.player_id and b.weCareAbout=a.score_date
order by a.player_id;
+-----------+-------+
| player_id | score |
+-----------+-------+
|       100 |  1100 |
|       101 |  1750 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Keeping in mind that I think your expected results are wrong. Their final score, not the high score.

Comment: awesome! I think this will work, let me try that now :)

Comment: As per my own answer - it'll work, but it won't be efficient.  (Won't scale.)  If this is to be a high-throughput query, with a lot of data behind it, I'd look at denormalising.

Comment: edit performed to show 2 queries to remove any ambiguity from my read on the question

Answer (score 0):

It's a pivot-table-sort-of-problem, for which MySQL unfortunately isn't super efficient.

Subqueries and `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` can get you the results you're after, but performance will drop substantially.

For an inefficient solution (using subqueries) for example: *(Nowhere to test this, syntax might not be spot on...)*

```
SELECT player_id, score
FROM scores
INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT
        MAX(`date`) AS `latestScoreDateTime`,
        player_id
     FROM scores
     WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2015-10-10'
     GROUP BY player_id
  ) AS sub1 ON (
     sub1.lastestScoreDateTime = scores.date AND
     sub1.player_id = scores.player_id
  )
```

But put an `EXPLAIN` on the front of that - and you'll see performance isn't good at all.

Personally (having worked on some big databases with big datasets and these sorts of problems to solve, all requiring speed and efficiency) I'd handle all the database inserts through a stored procedure (or your own data-access-layer in your application, or [*shudder*] through triggers).

This abstraction layer would maintain a "latestForDate" field.  A stored procedure can do this in a transactionally safe manner.

I've not got a test area to prove this - but the syntax would look something approximately like this:

```
DELIMTIER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddPlayerScore (IN fin_playerId INT UNSIGNED, IN fin_score INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
   DECLARE pToday DATETIME;

   START TRANSACTION;
       SET pToday = CURDATE();

       UPDATE scores SET latest_for_date=NULL
       WHERE latest_for_date=pToday AND player_id=fin_playerId;

       INSERT INTO scores SET
          latest_for_date=pToday,
          score=fin_score,
          player_id=fin_playerId;
   COMMIT;
END$$
```

Thusly you (transactionally safely) maintain a denormalised (efficient for reading!) way of getting the highest score:

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE latest_for_date='2015-10-10' GROUP BY player_id;
```

Comment: I can only comment on the last half of what you wrote. Your update stomps over all players (as you know). Next only the last insert has a curdate() not null for what was curdate() prior to your update stmt. Which means that is a big question mark. There is also the stroke of midnight problem where your two commands will act different than expected, so it is not military grade. And other things, like the fact that you are unnecessarily touching data that should be left alone and performance problems that you mentioned in your comment to me

Comment: so, everything that was of curdate except for your last insert will have a null, and that is just wrong imho

Comment: Thanks for catching the obvious - I've updated my answer.  Maintaining a denormalised flag is (in my experience) the only way read performance will remain scalable - having worked on a reasonably large financial application, questions like "how much balance remains on the account" or "what was the last transaction to occur" or "what was the balance at the close of the date" etc...

Comment: but that is where incrementing id's work. In financial data one does not go back and tweak prior rows in any way, even for the likes of clue columns like the tack-on column that you have. What is, is. They use reversing entries (having done primarily accounting apps and financial apps myself). Too many SOX audits I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (not tested, could have syntax errors):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY 
TABLE t1 (player_id int not null, score int not null, score_date datetime),UNIQUE KEY(player_id,score_date));
REPLACE INTO t1 SELECT player_id, score, score_date
FROM tbl_name
WHERE DATE(score_date) = '2015-10-01' order by player_id,score_date;
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT player_id, score, score_date
      FROM player
      ORDER BY score_date DESC
     ) temp
GROUP BY player_id, score_date
```